# Program for weekly control sport norms

Tags: project-management, reminders, fitness

I search a program that will help me to control my sport norms of every week, example:

- make 120 000 steps every week
- make 50 push-ups three times a week
- make 30 pull-ups two times a week
- etc.

The program's interface can look as:

- 7 of columns (1 day - 1 column)
  Column has items (1 item - 1 exercise, example "push-ups"), that planned or already occurred, if this day is past.
  Item has "name of an exercise", "number of reps" and "spent time".
- List of exercise
  Every exercise has norm of time and norm of reps
  Norm Of Time is variable, that will change when I will spend time this exercise
  Norm Of Reps is variable, that will change when I will do reps this exercise
  If i will do new exercise (not from list), I can to add this exercise in list and set his norms
  I can split exercise into 2 groups: required and other

The program should simplify the control of a weekly plan.

Plugins, Android apps, Web apps, PC apps or anything else.